# How to predict new values using statsmodels.formula.api (python)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I trained the logistic model using the following, from breast cancer data and ONLY using one feature 'mean_area'

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import logit
logistic_model = logit('target ~ mean_area',breast)
result = logistic_model.fit()
```

There is a built in predict method in the trained model. However that gives the predicted values of all the training samples. As follows

```
predictions = result.predict()
```

Suppose I want the prediction for a new value say 30 How do I used the trained model to out put the value? (rather than reading the coefficients and computing manually)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can provide new values to the `.predict()` model as illustrated in output #11 in this [notebook](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/discrete_choice.html) from the docs for a single observation. You can provide multiple observations as `2d array`, for instance a `DataFrame` - [see docs](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.predict.html#statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.predict).

Since you are using the formula API, your input needs to be in the form of a `pd.DataFrame` so that the column references are available. In your case, you could use something like `.predict(pd.DataFrame({'mean_area': [1,2,3]})`.

`statsmodels` `.predict()` uses the observations used for fitting only as default when no alternative is provided.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had a look at the notebook, however in my case when I try to give .predict(30) it throws an error " 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'' .

Comment: You are getting this error because the `exog` parameter has to be `array-like`, so you'd have to use `[30]`. Arrays have `getitem` method because they can contain multiple items in contrast to `int`.

Comment: Thanks when I try .predict([30])  I get the following error. "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

Comment: Sorry because of the formula api the input as to be as `DataFrame`, see updated answer.

Comment: Note that you can simply pass a dictionary into any of statsmodel's API's that accept dataframes - there is no need to create a dataframe unnecessarily. The following example notebook shows this in the last step: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/predict.html

Comment: The links listed are now dead.

Answer (score 1):

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf


model = smf.ols('y ~ x', data=df).fit()

# Predict for a list of observations, list length can be 1 to many..**
prediction = model.get_prediction(exog=dict(x=[5,10,25])) 
prediction.summary_frame(alpha=0.05)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulty predicting values using a fresh pandas dataframe.
So I added data to be predicted to original dataset post fitting

```
   y = data['price']
   x1 = data[['size', 'year']]
   data.columns
   #Index(['price', 'size', 'year'], dtype='object')
   x=sm.add_constant(x1)
   results = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
   results.summary()
   ## predict on unknown data
   data = data.append(pd.DataFrame({'size': [853.0,777], 'year': [2012.0,2013], 'price':[None, None]}))
   data.tail()
   new_x = data.loc[data.price.isnull(), ['size', 'year']]
   results.predict(sm.add_constant(new_x))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered but I hope this will help.

According to the documentation, the first parameter is "exog".

> exog : array_like, optional
> The values for which you want to predict

Further it says,

> "If a formula was used, then exog is processed in the same way as the
> original data. This transformation needs to have key access to the
> same variable names, and can be a pandas DataFrame or a dict like
> object that contains numpy arrays.
>
> If no formula was used, then the provided exog needs to have the same
> number of columns as the original exog in the model. No transformation
> of the data is performed except converting it to a numpy array.
>
> Row indices as in pandas data frames are supported, and added to the
> returned prediction"

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import logit

logistic_model = logit('target ~ mean_area',breast)
result = logistic_model.fit()
```

Therefore, you can provide a pandas dataframe (Ex: df) for the exog parameter and the dataframe should contain mean_area as a column. Because 'mean_area' is the predictor or the independent variable.

```
predictions = logistic_model.predict(exog=df)
```